# FTP folders mounted locally used for SVN repository

Tags: linux, svn, ftp

I would like to create a SVN repository remotely using FTP protocol.
Is it advisable to do the following steps

1. mount the FTP directory as local with culftpfs
2. create a repository as if it is local with svnadmin create
3. use it like in everyday life?

Do you know any issue with that approach?

RESULT AFTER MY ATTEMPT

I did try an attempy but I get an errro that looks like a timeout. THe real problem is that this approach is too slow. The solution of copying the repository each time looks more feasable or a simple script to back-up the folder.

Comment: I doubt such a filesystem would provide the locking semantics that svm expects

Comment: Any reason why you need to access your repo directly from FTP? A more feasible approach would be to use a local repo and occasionally sync it to FTP. If it's only the files you need on FTP (rather than the whole repo) you could even automate the pushing of a working copy to FTP using commit hooks.

Comment: Right because I didn't want to use any script to upload the repository, but I guess that is the most I can get until I don't have my server to acess via SSH or HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a dangerous approach, however if you are working alone(as in "single user"), it would work. The biggest problems are:

- You cannot provide exclusive locking mechanics over network
- All Users will have direct access to all repositorie's internal files, if somebody deletes a file in revs, your repository is damaged beyond repair

You should setup an apache with

```
SVNAutoversioning on
```

then you could mount your repoURL as WebDav folder. Each change on these files will result in a single commit without need of a workingcopy

Comment: @PeterPaerker: Thanks a lot! As far as I am now I am the only user of the repository. I definetly think that is better to have my own server+static ip and access it without extra complications.